# Rshiny gives error after loading rpart.object type using .RData file

Tags: r, shiny

I have saved the .Rdata file, which contains 3 R objects:

```
1. Vector
2. Character String
3. rpart.object (I figured out that this object in .RData only creating issue, as if I remove this object from .RData file, Shiny app works fine.)
```

Whenever I load the .RData file and refresh the application Rshiny gives error below:

Error in .rs.getShinyFunction(params$name, params$where) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

In order to avoid above issue, I tries following options:

1. Load the .RData in Global environment.

   ```
       load(infile$datapath,.GlobalEnv)
   ```
2. Load the .RData in New Environment.

   ```
   LoadToEnvironment <- function(RData, env = new.env())       { load(RData, env)  
    return(env) }
   ```

   e <- LoadToEnvironment("D:\Demo NBA\AddOnPropensity.R")
     val_modtyp <- e$val_modtyp
     val_model <- e$val_model
     val_b <-  e$val_b
3. Load data Using attach()

## Code:

```
require(shinydashboard)||install.packages("shinydashboard"); library(shinydashboard)  
require(shiny)||install.packages("shiny"); library(shiny)  
require(shinyjs)||install.packages("shinyjs"); library(shinyjs) 


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.refresh = function() { location.reload(); }"),
  fluidPage(id="Q1",useShinyjs(),

            dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title="Test",titleWidth=400),
                          dashboardSidebar(),

                          dashboardBody (


                            tabItem("PMData",
                                    fileInput('filepm', 'Choose Data to Upload',accept = c(".R")),
                                    uiOutput('ui.PM2'),
                                    actionButton("savepm","Save"),
                                    uiOutput("ui.PM3")
                            )
                          )
            )

  ))

server <- function(session,input,output){

  hide("savepm")

  dfPM <<- data.frame(Category=character(),
                      PredictiveModel=character(),
                      OfferIdentifier=character(),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)




  LoadToEnvironment <<- function(RData, env = new.env())
  {  
    load(RData, env)  
    return(env) }

  val_choices <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$filepm)){
      return()      
    }
    infile <- input$filepm    
    e <- LoadToEnvironment(infile$datapath)
    e$val_b
  }) 



  observeEvent(input$filepm,{

    useShinyjs()
    if (is.null(input$filepm)){
      return()      
    }

    output$ui.PM2 <- renderUI ({
      selectInput("offered",label= "Offered Test",choices = val_choices(),
                  selected = NULL)
    })
    show("ui.PM2")
    show("savepm")
  })

  val_pmfile <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$filepm)){
      return()      
    }
    infile <- input$filepm
    infile$datapath
  }) 

  TempPredmodDF <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$offered))
    {
      return()
    }else{
      data.frame(Category="Test",
                 PredictiveModel=val_pmfile(),
                 OfferIdentifier=input$offered,
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}
  })

  observeEvent(input$savepm,
{  
  useShinyjs()

  tempPMdf <- TempPredmodDF()


  if(nrow(dfPM[dfPM$Category==tempPMdf$Category,]) == 0)
  {
    dfPM <<- rbind(dfPM,tempPMdf)
  }else
  {
    getidx <- as.numeric(which( dfPM[,1] == tempPMdf$Category ))

    dfPM[getidx,2] <<- tempPMdf$PredictiveModel

    dfPM[getidx,3] <<- tempPMdf$OfferIdentifier

  }

  output$ui.PM3 <- renderTable({
    dfPM},include.rownames=FALSE)

  hide("ui.PM2")
  hide("savepm")
  show("ui.PM3")

})

}


app <- shinyApp(ui,server)

runApp(app,port = 7000,launch.browser = getOption("shiny.launch.browser", interactive()))
```

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but just FYI: you only need to call `useShinyjs()` ONCE in the UI. You don't need to call it at all in the server. So you can safely remove all calls to it and just leave the first one

Comment: I have put the .Rdata file,which i used to upload for this code on Google forum. This will better help you to reproduce the problem.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/WUVlG4IZADM

I am using RStudio Version 0.98.1062.
Shiny Version - 0.12.1
R Version - 3.1.3

Comment: Code Snippet: require(shiny)||install.packages("shiny"); library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fileInput('filepm', 'Choose Data to Upload',accept = c(".R")))

server <- function(session,input,output){
  
  LoadToEnvironment <<- function(RData, env = new.env())
  { load(RData, env)
    return(env) }
  
  val_choices <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$filepm)){
      return() }
    infile <- input$filepm
    
    e <- LoadToEnvironment(infile$datapath)
    e$val_b
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$filepm,{ 
    if (is.null(input$filepm)){
      return()}
    
    val_choices()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/WUVlG4IZADM

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Please run simple code in comment above.
2. Upload .Rdata file from google link above.
3. Refresh the application.
4. It will give error below on R Studio Command line:
Error in .rs.getShinyFunction(params$name, params$where) : 
attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Issue is resolved after R version upgraded from 3.1.2 to 3.2.1.

Thank you for your help.